# How return promise from multiple promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I always in console see:

1. teamsUpdated2
2. addUserToProjects
3. deleteUserFromProjects

but should bee in different order

```
var result = teamService.addOrDeleteUser(userId, newTeams, deleteTeams);
result.then(function () {
     console.log("teamsUpdated2");          
     });
```

function with multiple promises:

```
var _addOrDeleteUser = function (userId, addToProjects, removeFromProjects) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    promises.push(projectResource.addUserToProjects({ userId: userId }, addToProjects, function (result) {
        console.log("addUserToProjects");
        deferred.resolve();
        return result;
    }));

    promises.push(projectResource.deleteUserFromProjects({ userId: userId }, removeFromProjects, function (result) {
        console.log("deleteUserFromProjects");
        deferred.resolve();
        return result;
    }));

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of these two methods as well please? `projectResource.addUserToProjects` and `projectResource.deleteUserFromProjects`

Comment: Also, your `deferred` seems to be doing nothing - you could just remove the lines `var deferred = $q.defer();` and those two occurences of `deferred.resolve();`

Comment: Are you sure that the function `addUserToProjects` and `deleteUserFromProjects` return a promise? P.S. https://jsfiddle.net/hLk0oruy/

Answer (score 2):

You can use promise chaining for that -

```
travelService
       .getDeparture( user )                                           // Request #1
       .then( function( departure ){
            $scope.departure = departure;                            // Response Handler #1
            return travelService.getFlight( departure.flightID );       // Request #2
        })
        .then( function( flight ){
             $scope.flight = flight;                                // Response Handler #2
             return weatherService.getForecast( $scope.departure.date ); // Request #3
        })
        .then( function( weather ){
            $scope.weather = weather;                               // Response Handler #3
        });
```

For more reference see [this](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I think your promise chain example is the correct approach.

Comment: As I understood the question, OP was wondering why "teamsUpdated2" was logged first although it should be chained after both the other promises have resolved.

Comment: @Chips_100  i think he is asking that every time he is checking console promise order is different so he need some method so order can be same always.

Comment: @AmitSirohiya Let's just see if OP comes back to clarify - as your answer is definitely a helpful example and related to the problem, +1 from me!