# AngularJS: Chaining multiple promises with conditions

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, callback, promise, angular-promise

I'm writing with AngularJS 1.6. I have several http calls to make in order, and depends on previous http calls results. How do I properly chain the promises, to make sure all the callbacks are resolved, and avoid callback hell, and handle errors? The pseudo code would be:

```
httpCall1.then(result1){
    if (result1) {
        doSomething1
    }
    else {
        httpCall2.then(result2) {
           if (result2) {
               httpCall3.then() {
                   doSomething3
               }
           }
           else {
               doSomething2
           }
    }
```

Could you show me what the actual code would look like? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think your pseudo code is the correct code. You need to check the response before calling the new resource.

Comment: But wouldn't that cause callback hell? Everything I read is we should flatten our chained promises.

Comment: I do not think you be able to do so. As I said before, you have to check the response before calling a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pretty much like that. Just use actual callback function syntax and don't forget to `return` the inner promises from the `then` callbacks.

```
httpCall1().then(result1 => {
    if (result1) {
        return doSomething1();
    } else {
        return httpCall2().then(result2 => {
            if (result2) {
                return httpCall3().then(() => {
                    return doSomething3();
                });
            } else {
                return doSomething2();
            }
        });
    }
}).then(result => { // fulfills with the result from the respective doSomething
    …
}).catch(err => { // any rejections can be handled here
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: So I don't need to try to flatten my promises like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004659/how-return-promise-from-multiple-promises

Comment: You never *need* to flatten promises, that's just for visual appeal. But in this case, you *cannot* flatten conditional branches.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The doSomething1, 2, 3 are not promises. Only the httpCalls are. So no need to return doSomethings? Or do I still need to return some kind of promise? But how?

Comment: You can return plain values from `then` callbacks as well, they fulfill the result promise directly.

Comment: What if my doSomething() functions don't return any value? Say they are setters. Can I just return true? So it would be:

httpCall1().then(result1 => {
    if (result1) {
        doSomething1();
        return true;
    } else {
        return httpCall2().then(result2 => {
            if (result2) {
                return httpCall3().then(() => {
                    doSomething3();
                    return true;
                });
            } else {
                doSomething2();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
...

Comment: Well if you don't *need* a result, you can just not return anything, then `result` in the next callback will be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The unique way to avoid Callback hell is using `ES2017 async/await` syntax

```
async function foo () {
    try {
        var result1 = await httpCall1() //The .then(val =>) is in result1
        if (result1) {
            doSomething1()
        } else {
            var result2 = await httpCall2()
            if (result2) {
                await httpCall3()
                doSomething3()
            } else {
                doSomething2()
            }
        }           
    } catch (e) { console.log(e) } //Here you catch all errors and rejects
}
foo()
```

Whit this syntax you can make asynchronous `for...loops` that will stop until each request complete

```
async function foo () {
    try {
        var item = await $http.get('/item')
        var users = await $http.get('/user/' + item.id)

        for (var user of users)
            user.car = await $http.get('/car/' + user.id);

        return users

    } catch (e) { console.log(e) } //Any reject here
}
```

Comment: The syntax isn't much better than the original in this particular case. Also, the way the for-loop is constructed, the requests will run sequentially when they might as well be run in parallel.